# Coordinates of clicked object relative to the same clicked object

Tags: three.js

I have rotating object (sphere). When I click on an object, I get coordinates relative to camera by:

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( cameradestinations, true );
```

How can I get this coordinates relative to clicked object position, not to scene center?

(yes I can make clicked.point - clicked.position, but is here something smarter? )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a vector with World coordinates and want them in an objects Local space, you can use the .worldToLocal() method in Object3D class.

```
intersectedObject.worldToLocal(point);
```

Comment: that simple? man thank you! i just created a function doing the same. Did that reflects rotation of object?

Comment: I mean if intersectedObject is rotating and i click him, did i get point vector like object is in zero rotation, or i get the same like clicked.point - clicked.position result?